# i want to show multiple selected data in PHP

Tags: php

I want show multiple selected languages from dropdown but it shows only one

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
        $getuser = $user->search($_SESSION['id'], $_POST);
}

<select class="selectpicker btn btn-outline-light mx-0" data-width="fit" name="lang[]" multiple="" >

            <?php while($row = $getlang->fetch_assoc()):; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['lang_id']; ?>">

               <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
                <?php endwhile ?>
            </option>
 </select>

<?php

public function search($id,$data){

        $lang_id= $_REQUEST['lang'];


        foreach($data['lang'] as $value) {


        $q = "SELECT * FROM (



        SELECT user_table.fname,user_table.lname, languages.name,languages.lang_id
        FROM interested
        INNER JOIN user_table ON interested.u_id = user_table.id 
        INNER JOIN languages ON interested.lang_id = languages.lang_id
        WHERE NOT user_table.id='$id'

        ) AS I WHERE I.lang_id='$value'  ";

        }

        $result = $this->connection->query($q);

        return $result;
}
```

Comment: did you try putting the $result inside you foreach?

Comment: Yes i tried but still showing one language

Comment: you can try like this `$result[] = $this->connection->query($q);

        print_r($result);` inside the foreach loop

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put the **endwhile tag** outside of the **closing option tag**. So your select option will look like this:

```
<select class="selectpicker btn btn-outline-light mx-0" data-width="fit" name="lang[]" multiple>
     <?php while($row = $getlang->fetch_assoc()): ?>
     <option value="<?php echo $row['lang_id']; ?>">
          <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
     </option>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
 </select>
```